# VS Code retrieve Profile data

Tags: salesforcedx, profile, vs-code, custom-profile, sfdx-plugin

I retrieved with VS code all my profile, with 

        *
        Profile

in  package.xml. But in definition of a profile "profileName-meta.xml", i can't find userPermission with false value.
Anyone can help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DnbFAAS
[Profile Metadata Question - False User permissions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63477/profile-metadata-question-false-user-permissions)

If they don't have a userpermission, then it wouldn't be there as opposed to being set to "false". Profiles retrieved by the metadata API only include granted permissions (those with "true" value).